# Scanning, spliting and assigning values from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, loops, split, java.util.scanner

I'm having trouble scanning a given file for certain words and assigning them to variables, so far I've chosen to use Scanner over BufferedReader because It's more familiar. I'm given a text file and this particular part I'm trying to read the first two words of each line (potentially unlimited lines) and maybe add them to an array of sorts. This is what I have:

```
    File file = new File("example.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] ary = line.split(",");
```

I know It' a fair distance off, however I'm new to coding and cannot get past this wall...

An example input would be...

```
ExampleA ExampleAA, <other items seperated by ",">
ExampleB ExampleBB, <other items spereated by ",">
...
```

and the proposed output

```
VariableA = ExampleA ExampleAA
VariableB = ExampleB ExampleBB
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
    File file = new File("D:\\test.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
    int i=0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
      list.add(sc.nextLine().split(",",2)[0]);
      i++;
    }
    char point='A';
    for(String str:list){
        System.out.println("Variable"+point+" = "+str);
        point++;
    }
```

My input:

```
ExampleA ExampleAA, <other items seperated by ",">
ExampleB ExampleBB, <other items spereated by ",">
```

Out put:

```
VariableA = ExampleA ExampleAA
VariableB = ExampleB ExampleBB
```

Comment: @RaviThapliyal run this code and try. can't you see `point++` here? Can't you see my output here?

Comment: Nice, thanks. One more thing, if I were to read a second item (in the part I have labeled other items...) and add it to a different array list, how would that differ from the code you have written. Just the while loop contents, I cant seem to replicate this.

Comment: @Harry if you want 2nd item only, change `.split(",",3)[1]`. that's it

Comment: I just tested the same code with the changed split and got an exception, arrayindexoutofbounds.

Comment: @Ruchira, OIC. Excuse my oversight please. You have my +1 and I'd go get myself some coffee :)

Comment: @ Ruchira I'm having issues with the .split function still. Changing array index to any number other than 0 give an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase, you are looking to read the first 2 words of a line (everything before the first comma) and store it in a variable to process further.

To do so, your current code looks fine, however, when you grab the line's data, use the `substring` function in conjunction with `indexOf` to just get the first part of the String before the comma. After that, you can do whatever processing you want to do with it.

In your current code, ary[0] should give you the first 2 words.

Comment: That's a much better way to put it. Thanks! I'll try that out, would I have to declare each variable and assign it a value from the file using substring and indexOf?

Comment: You don't have to :) It all depends on what you want to do with it afterwards. If the input file may be large, you're better off processing each line as you go through the file. Compare that to the case where you store all the results in an array and then after you're done reading the file, process everything. You would have to store a lot of values in that case.

Comment: Ah okay. The plan was to create a class which would operate as explained, obtaining the value for each variable and having those variables (and their value) available for other classes to access, mostly printing out. Any final suggestions where to head from here?

Comment: Gotcha, well in that case, you should store them. I would have that class (let's say `Repository`) have an `Add` method that your parser calls and passes the parsed values. I would also put error checks in place to take care of scenarios where the input line does not have any comma for example. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
             {
        File file = new File("example.txt");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = "";
        List l = new ArrayList();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = line.trim(); // remove unwanted characters at the end of line
            String[] arr = line.split(",");
            String[] ary = arr[0].split(" ");
            String firstTwoWords[] = new String[2];
            firstTwoWords[0] = ary[0];
            firstTwoWords[1] = ary[1];
            l.add(firstTwoWords);
        }

        Iterator it = l.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String firstTwoWords[] = (String[]) it.next();

            System.out.println(firstTwoWords[0] + " " + firstTwoWords[1]);
        }

    }
```